# How to get 5 words from database and put it in slider caption

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write simple function to get 5 words from table wp_posts and post_content row in wordpress and put it In carousel caption:

```
<div class="caption">
<time class="the-date" datetime="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_time('c')); ?>">
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_date()); ?></time>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<p>(here i want to put function)</p></div>
```

and this is my myqsql query

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content," ",5) from wp_posts WHERE `ID`= (id_of_post)
```

I need help with answering for questions below

How to get currently post ID and how to put it between `<p>` tags

Now I'm having:

```
$getfewwords = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,' ',8) from wp_posts WHERE ID = 1
```

And It almost works , only question is how to get currently post ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution below:

```
       <?php 
$getfewwords = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,' ',8) from wp_posts WHERE `ID`='$post->ID' " );
echo "<h3>{$getfewwords}</h3>";
?>
```

Hope it helped somebody.